# Cypress environment variable file is not push to git

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I am using Jenkins pipeline and Cypress. In Cypress I am using environment variable, but I didn't push the `cypress.env.json` to the git server.

From Jenkins pipeline, the test project is pull from git server, and continue with `cypress run`, but the problem is all the url path is define in the env.json file, since the cypress.env.json is not push initially, I hit with path not found problem

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

This is neither cypress issue nor jenkins. It looks like how you are committing the file and the path of that file. However I want to take a look at the issue and help you if you can provide the `cypress.env.json` file and `full error log` that you are getting.

Please show how you are committing  this file to git repo so that we can pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Only cypress.env.json.example is committed to the git server.